# Bibliography problem

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, natbib

I have a problem when using a `bib` file in my `tex` this is the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}
.
.
.
\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
\bibliography{mybib} % Path to your References.bib file
\end{document}
```

This is the bib file:

```
@Article{ROCForMedical,
author = {"Rajeev Kumar and Abhaya Indrayan"},
title = {"Receiver Operating Characteristic (ROC) Curve for Medical Researchers"},
journal = {"INDIAN PEDIATRICS"},
year = {"2011"},
OPTvolume = {"48"},
OPTpages = {"277-287"},
OPTmonth = {"April"}
}

@Article{Fisher36,
author = {Fisher, R. A.},
title = {The use of multiple measurements in taxonomic problem},
journal = {Ann Eugen},
year = {1936},
OPTnumber = {7},
OPTpages = {179-188}
}
@Book{introR,
author = {Gareth James and Daniela Witten and Trevor Hastie and Robert Tibshirani},
title = {An Introduction to Statistical Learning with Applications in R},
publisher = {Springer},
year = {2013}
}
.
.
.
@Book{MDA,
author = {William Cooley and Paul Lohnes},
title = {Multivariate Data Analysis},
publisher = {John Wiley \& Sons, LTD},
year = {1971}
}
```

So, the problem is that when I compile it the PDF comes like this:

[image]

So, can you help me, please?

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Since you are not using `biblatex` I have removed that tag. The code you have shown us looks innocent enough to me, so I guess the problem must lie elsewhere. Please post an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) that we can run and shows the problem.

Comment: @JosephWright the problem is show on the picture,  the references are not come line by line.

Comment: The `.bib` file edit is welcome but doesn't show the issue: with the preamble as-shown each reference comes out separately. You'll need to make sure that the `.tex` code you give is a _complete_ example showing the issue.

Comment: I just ran your example (I just removed the three dots in the `.bib`) and cannot reproduce the problem. Note that `author = {"Rajeev Kumar and Abhaya Indrayan"},` is probably wrong and you want only `author = {Rajeev Kumar and Abhaya Indrayan},` instead; in fact the entire first entry suffers from this problem, remove the `"`s. As I said we need a real MWE (see link above) that properly reproduces the problem to investigate what's going on.

Comment: Note also that the `OPT` fields are all ignored by BibTeX, so you'll never get to see the pages and number in the output (not sure if that is intentional).

Answer (score 2):

(too long for a comment, hence posted as an answer)

The undesirable formatting you've encountered does not appear to be caused by the code you've posted so far, as the code shown below demonstrates. Not having access to the full document, I'm afraid it's not useful to speculate on which settings have been modified to generate the undesirable formatting. You may want to look if some of the code in your document (or in a package loaded by your document) modifies settings of the low-level `list` environment, which is employed by LaTeX to create the formatted bibliography.

For sure, you should not habitually enclose each and every field with pairs of both double quotes and curly braces. Use one or the other type of delimiter, *but not both*. (Use "inner" delimiters only if you need to (a) inform BibTeX that a certain author should be treated as "corporate author" or (b) prevent BibTeX from lowercasing certain words or letters if so-called sentence style is in effect.) Separately, you should also remove the "OPT" prefixes from various fields.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@Article{ROCForMedical,
author  = "Rajeev Kumar and Abhaya Indrayan",
title   = "Receiver Operating Characteristic ({ROC}) Curve for Medical Researchers",
journal = "Indian Pediatrics",
year    = "2011",
volume  = "48",
pages   = "277-287",
month   = "April",
}
@Article{Fisher36,
author  = {Fisher, Ronald A.},
title   = {The use of multiple measurements in taxonomic problem},
journal = {Ann. Eugen},
year    = {1936},
number  = {7},
pages   = {179-188}
}
@Book{introR,
author    = {Gareth James and Daniela Witten and Trevor Hastie and Robert Tibshirani},
title     = {An Introduction to Statistical Learning with Applications in~R},
publisher = {Springer},
year      = {2013}
}
@Book{MDA,
author    = {William Cooley and Paul Lohnes},
title     = {Multivariate Data Analysis},
publisher = {John Wiley \& Sons, Ltd.},
year      = {1971}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{abbrv}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```